# Why data isn't inserted into SQLite database? (Room+rx)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rx-java2, android-room

I need to insert data to database with the help of such instrument as Room. Here's the way how I do it:

It is my `DAO` interface

```
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Observable;

@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Completable insertMovie(final MovieEntity movie);

}
```

Here's the method, which should add data to db:

```
@Override
public void addMovieToFavorites(@Nonnull Bundle bundle) {
    String url = bundle.getString(MovieListFragment.EXTRA_IMAGE);
    int watchers = bundle.getInt(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_WATCHERS);
    String name = bundle.getString(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME);

    MovieDatabase database = TraktTvApp.getInstance().getDatabase();
    MovieDao movieDao = database.movieDao();
    MovieEntity movieEntity = new MovieEntity(name, watchers, url);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity))
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
            .doOnError(throwable -> mView.onMovieDetailsFailed())
            .doOnComplete(() -> mView.onMoviesAdded())
            .doOnTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe()
    );
}
```

But unfortunately data isn't added to db, as I see in Stetho. So, what's the matter? Data, which I want to add is not null and there are no errors while running (as onComplete method is called). As I think there's a problem in rx logic, but I am a newbie in it and can't understand why my problem happens

**UPD**

I changed rx logic in the following way:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable(() -> movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError(throwable -> mView.onMovieDetailsFailed())
        .doOnComplete(() -> mView.onMoviesAdded())
        .doAfterTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
        .subscribe()
);
```

But it still doesn't work

**UPD 2**

```
    mCompositeDisposable.add(movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> mView.onMovieDetailsFailed())
            .doOnComplete(() -> mView.onMoviesAdded())
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
            .subscribe()
    );
```

Comment: You are not subscribing to `insertMovie()`. `insertMovie()` is ignored. To fix this, change `Observable.fromCallable(() -> movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity))` to just `movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity)`

Comment: @SanlokLee, I changed in this way but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you post how you changed. Also checking whether `mCompositeDisposable` is already disposed or not can help.

Comment: @SanlokLee, updated the question